ODE and SDE on Spheres $S^{n-1}$
I'm looking for comprehensive references (books or papers) that cover the theory and applications of Ordinary Differential Equations (ODEs) and Stochastic Differential Equations (SDEs) on $S^{n-1}$ spheres. Additionally, could anyone provide a brief explanation or overview of these topics? How can a continuous flow be confined on a sphere, or more generally, on a manifold?

ODEs: if of first order, they are nothing else than vector fields. SDEs: The usual suspect contains the standard references.
